# configure Postfix to send diferent user through same relay depending on domain

Tags: postfix

I need to configure postfix to send through a relay server but with different user depending on the sender domain. For example:

```
domain1.com
userA
passwordA

domain2.com
userB
passwordB
```

I need to send though **relay.server.com**

These are the files that I've changed unsucesfuly:

/etc/postfix/transport

> ```
> .domain1.com      smtp:[relay.server.com]
> .domain2.com      smtp:[relay.server.com]
> ```

/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

> ```
>  @domain1.com         userA:passwordA
>  @domain2.com         userB:passwordB
> ```

/etc/postfix/relayhost_map

> ```
>  domain1.com   smtp:[relay.server.com]
>  domain2.com   smtp:[relay.server.com]
> ```

/etc/postfix/main.cf

> ```
> mydomain = domain3.com
> myhostname = host.domain3.com
> myorigin = $mydomain
> relay_domains = relay.server.com, domain1.com, domain2.com
> relayhost = [relay.server.com]
> sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relayhost_map
> smtp_pix_workarounds = delay_dotcrlf
> smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
> smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = !gssapi, !external, static:all
> smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
> smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
> smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtp_sasl_security_options
> smtp_sasl_type = cyrus
> smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
> smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
> smtp_use_tls = yes
> smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
> smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
> soft_bounce = no
> transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
> unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
> virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
> ```

The error that I got is:

> ```
> Feb 13 19:04:43 postfixserver postfix/smtp[2718]: 95EE11607CC: to=<noreply@domain1.com>, relay=relay.server.com[X.X.X.X]:25, delay=0.28, delays=0/0.04/0.14/0.11, dsn=5.7.0, status=bounced (host relay.server.com[X.X.X.X] said: 530 5.7.0 authentication required in "MAIL FROM:<> SIZE=2263 BODY=8BITMIME" (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
> ```

seems that sasl_passwd mapping are not defined correctly. 
thanks in advance

Comment: Did relay.server.com need TLS to do authentication and relay?

Comment: Or you can use debug mode by adding this line `debug_peer_list = [relay.server.com]` to main.cf. Source [this page](http://www.postfix.org/DEBUG_README.html#debug_peer)

Comment: yes, the relay server needs TLS authentication.

Comment: I followed these instructions and it's working now. Thanks. http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2009/03/13/configure-postfix-for-multiple-isp-client-smtp-authentication/

Comment: Congratulations, can you write up what's difference between non-working and working configuration in the answer section below? It'll help future visitors who have same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved doing some changes on these files:

I added the "@" before the domain and I deleted the "smtp:" tag before the server:

```
/etc/postfix/relayhost_map
 @domain1.com   [relay.server.com]
 @domain2.com   [relay.server.com]
```

I also changed the relayhost on the main.cf file to trace if the configuration was working.

Comment: Thank you! The @domain1.com format worked well in /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd as well.